# Ruby on rails problems on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I've been working on a  on uploading my RoR3 website onto Heroku.

Took me a while to get it up. Seems to work pretty good but when i try creating a project (my website manges donation projects) i get the next message:

`We're sorry, but something went wrong. We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.`

No idea what causes this it works fine on my localhost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal Rails Error - Have a look at the [Heroku Logs](http://docs.heroku.com/logging) and check the Stack for more details then post them back on here.

Comment: You should still be able to use the `heroku logs` command to get output of recent logs on your app.  Also check out http://docs.heroku.com/exceptional - Exceptional is a free service that is easy to set up that gives you email notifications when exceptions happen on your heroku app.

Answer (score 3):

Usually when I've had this problem, it's because I've forgotten to run db migrations at Heroku.

In terminal, in your rails app folder, run this:

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

If needed, you can find more info in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/refinery-cms/msg/9e6bf65846eb2906).